# DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 34359738368 bytes

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am new to Pytorch coding and recently have been working on a project on Pycharm, where the main goal to achieve is, my LSTM based neural network would classify an activity based on video input. The way this works is, my video input is first converted to individual image frames. Now based on the difference between each image frame, the activity is classified. Till now, I have been able to convert my video to image frames, but after that during the making of the neural network, I am getting an error. DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 34359738368 bytes.
I have tried decreasing the batch size, reducing the features, switched to a better, faster laptop but I haven't been able to solve the problem.

**CNN_Classification_Training.py**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import transforms,datasets, models
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy
import time
import os

os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
    use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()
    if use_gpu:
        pinMem = True
    else:
        pinMem = False
    
    trainDir = 'train_5class'
    valDir = 'test_5class'
    apply_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor()])


    train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(trainDir,transform=apply_transform)
    trainLoader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=True,num_workers=4, pin_memory=pinMem)

    test_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(valDir,transform=apply_transform)
    testLoader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=False,num_workers=4, pin_memory=pinMem)


    print('No. of samples in train set: '+str(len(trainLoader.dataset)))
    print('No. of samples in test set: '+str(len(testLoader.dataset)))

    net = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
    print(net)



    totalParams = 0
    for params in net.parameters():
        print(params.size())
        totalParams += np.sum(np.prod(params.size()))
    print('Total number of parameters: '+str(totalParams))

    net.fc = nn.Linear(512,101)

    iterations = 2

    trainLoss = []
    trainAcc = []
    testLoss = []
    testAcc = []

    start = time.time()
    for epoch in range(iterations):
        epochStart = time.time()
        runningLoss = 0.0
        avgTotalLoss = 0.0
        running_correct = 0
        count = 0
        net.train(True) # For training
        batchNum = 1
        for data in trainLoader:
            count=count+1
            print(count)
            inputs,labels = data

            if use_gpu:
                inputs, labels = Variable(inputs.cuda()), Variable(labels.cuda())
                outputs = net(inputs)
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                running_correct += (predicted.cpu() == labels.data.cpu()).sum()
            else:
                inputs, labels = Variable(inputs), Variable(labels)
                outputs = net(inputs)
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                running_correct += (predicted == labels.data).sum()
       

            optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
            optimizer.zero_grad()


            loss = criterion(F.log_softmax(outputs), labels)

            loss.backward()

            optimizer.step()

            runningLoss += loss.item()
            batchNum += 1

        avgTrainAcc = running_correct/float(len(trainLoader.dataset))
        avgTrainLoss = runningLoss/float(len(trainLoader.dataset))
        trainAcc.append(avgTrainAcc)
        trainLoss.append(avgTrainLoss)
    

        net.train(False)
        running_correct = 0
        cnt = 0
        print("GOING IN INNER FOR-LOOP")
        for data in testLoader:
            cnt = cnt+1
            print(cnt)
            inputs,labels = data
            # Wrap them in Variable
            if use_gpu:
                inputs, labels= Variable(inputs.cuda()), Variable(labels.cuda())
                outputs = net(inputs)
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                running_correct += (predicted.cpu() == labels.data.cpu()).sum()
            else:
                inputs, labels = Variable(inputs), Variable(labels)
                # Model 1
                outputs = net(inputs)
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                running_correct += (predicted == labels.data).sum()
        
            loss = criterion(F.log_softmax(outputs), labels)
        
            runningLoss += loss.item()

        avgTestLoss = runningLoss/float(len(testLoader.dataset))
        avgTestAcc = running_correct/float(len(testLoader.dataset))
        testAcc.append(avgTestAcc)
        testLoss.append(avgTestLoss)
    

        fig1 = plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(range(epoch+1),trainLoss,'r-',label='train')
        plt.plot(range(epoch+1),testLoss,'g-',label='test')
        if epoch==0:
            plt.legend(loc='upper left')
            plt.xlabel('Epochs')
            plt.ylabel('Loss')

        fig2 = plt.figure(2)
        plt.plot(range(epoch+1),trainAcc,'r-',label='train')
        plt.plot(range(epoch+1),testAcc,'g-',label='test')
        if epoch==0:
            plt.legend(loc='upper left')
            plt.xlabel('Epochs')
            plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
        
  
        
        epochEnd = time.time()-epochStart
        print('Iteration: {:.0f} /{:.0f};  Training Loss: {:.6f} ; Training Acc: {:.3f}'\
              .format(epoch + 1,iterations,avgTrainLoss,avgTrainAcc*100))
        print('Iteration: {:.0f} /{:.0f};  Testing Loss: {:.6f} ; Testing Acc: {:.3f}'\
              .format(epoch + 1,iterations,avgTestLoss,avgTestAcc*100))
   
        print('Time consumed: {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(epochEnd//60,epochEnd%60))
    end = time.time()-start
    print('Training completed in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(end//60,end%60))

    torch.save(net.state_dict(), 'resnet18Pre_fcOnly5class_ucf101_10adam_1e-4_b128.pt')
```

**CNN_Train.py**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision import models, transforms

from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np
import pickle


# Check availability of GPU
use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()

# Load train-test list
with open('trainList_5class.pckl','rb') as f:
    trainList = pickle.load(f)
with open('testList_5class.pckl','rb') as f:
    testList = pickle.load(f)
    
classes = []
for item in trainList:
    c = item.split('_')[1]
    if c not in classes:
        classes.append(c)

net = models.resnet18()
net.fc = nn.Linear(512,101)
# Loading saved states
net.load_state_dict(torch.load('resnet18Pre_fcOnly5class_ucf101_10adam_1e-4_b128.pt'))

# Removing fully connected layer for feature extraction
model = nn.Sequential(*list(net.children())[:-1])
if use_gpu:
    model = model.cuda()

data_transforms = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),            
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ])

framePath = 'frames/'
for item in trainList:
    cName = item.split('_')[1]
    srcPath = framePath+cName+'/'+item    
    fNames = os.listdir(srcPath)
    # filename template
    fTemplate = fNames[0].split('_')
    fCount = len(fNames)
    for fNum in range(fCount):
        fileName = fTemplate[0]+'_'+fTemplate[1]+'_'+fTemplate[2]+'_'+fTemplate[3]+'_'+str(fNum+1)+'.jpg'
        if os.path.exists(srcPath+'/'+fileName):
            # Loading image
            img = Image.open(srcPath+'/'+fileName)
            # Transform to tensor
            imgTensor = data_transforms(img).unsqueeze(0)
            if use_gpu:
                inp = Variable(imgTensor.cuda())
            else:
                inp = Variable(imgTensor)
            # Feed-forward through model+stack features for each video
            if fNum == 0:
                out = model(inp)                
                out = out.view(out.size()[0],-1).data.cpu()                
            else:
                out1 = model(inp)               
                out1 = out1.view(out1.size()[0],-1).data.cpu()                
                out = torch.cat((out,out1),0)
        else:
            print(fileName+ ' missing!')       
    # out dimension -> frame count x 512
    featSavePath = 'ucf101_resnet18Feat/train/'+cName # Directory for saving features
    if not os.path.exists(featSavePath):
        os.makedirs(featSavePath)
    torch.save(out,os.path.join(featSavePath,item+'.pt'))

framePath = 'frames/'
for item in testList:
    cName = item.split('_')[1]
    srcPath = framePath+cName+'/'+item    
    fNames = os.listdir(srcPath)
    fTemplate = fNames[0].split('_')
    fCount = len(fNames)
    for fNum in range(fCount):
        fileName = fTemplate[0]+'_'+fTemplate[1]+'_'+fTemplate[2]+'_'+fTemplate[3]+'_'+str(fNum+1)+'.jpg'
        if os.path.exists(srcPath+'/'+fileName):
            img = Image.open(srcPath+'/'+fileName)
            imgTensor = data_transforms(img).unsqueeze(0)
            inp = Variable(imgTensor.cuda())
            if fNum == 0:
                out = model(inp)                
                out = out.view(out.size()[0],-1).data.cpu()
                
            else:
                out1 = model(inp)               
                out1 = out1.view(out1.size()[0],-1).data.cpu()                
                out = torch.cat((out,out1),0)
        else:
            print(fileName+ ' missing!')
      
    featSavePath = 'ucf101_resnet18Feat/test/'+cName
    if not os.path.exists(featSavePath):
        os.makedirs(featSavePath)
    torch.save(out,os.path.join(featSavePath,item+'.pt'))
```

Comment: Try to change smaller `batch_size` and `num_workers` of `DataLoader`.